# stored procedure dont have inparams and outparams

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am writing a stored procedure to call my location path in database. What if there in none inparams and outparams in my stored procedure. 
    Code is like :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sqladmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_getLocation`()

BEGIN

SELECT Lo.LocationPath

FROM Location Lo   

WHERE CategoryID=1;

END
```

If i want to call this stored procedure in vb.net, how should i write it to call it. I know how to call it when we have inparmas and outparams or either of them. BUt no familar with none of them. So anyone could help?

```
      Friend Function getLocationPath() As DataSet
    Try
        Dim dbh As New DatabaseHandler
        Dim ds As DataSet
        ds = dbh.callProcReturn("sp_getLocation", nothing, Nothing)


        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception
        logException("getLocationpath", ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

Update for call procReturn Method

```
 Friend Function callProcReturn(ByVal procName As String, ByVal inParams As Hashtable, ByRef outParams As Hashtable, _
                               Optional ByRef inoutParams As Hashtable = Nothing) As DataSet
    logQuery("callProcReturn", procName, inParams, inoutParams)
    Dim elapsedTicks As Long
    Dim elapsedSpan As New TimeSpan(elapsedTicks)
    elapsedTicks = Date.Now.Ticks
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        'Add the parameters if required
        '
        If inParams Is Nothing Then
            inParams = New Hashtable
        End If
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_UserId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_UserId", ConfigurationHandler.UserId)
        End If
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_MachineId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_MachineId", ConfigurationHandler.machineId)
        End If
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_ApplicationId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_ApplicationId", ConfigurationHandler.applicationId)
        End If

        'Do the actual query
        '
        Select Case UCase(_dbType)
            Case "MYSQL"
                ds = callSQLProcReturn(procName, inParams, outParams, inoutParams)
            Case "XML"
                ds = _xmlDatabase.callXMLProcReturn(procName, inParams, outParams, inoutParams)
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("INVALID_DATABASE_TYPE")
        End Select

        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception                                   
        logException("callProcReturn", ex.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        logResult("callProcReturn", procName, outParams, inoutParams)
        elapsedSpan = New TimeSpan(Date.Now.Ticks - elapsedTicks)
        logVerbose("DatabaseHandler:callProcReturn[" & procName & "]-Elapsed: " & elapsedSpan.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If you run that code what happens?

Comment: the code is not working because this line ds = dbh.callProcReturn("sp_getLocation", nothing, Nothing). The syntax is wrong. It shouldn't be nothing, nothing, coz no in and outparams. I cant find out the right way to write this line

Comment: Then the problem is inside the callProcReturn. Could you show the code of that method?

Comment: ok. I will edit the question and you will see there.cheers

Comment: That method cannot be used. It forces adding parameters also when you don't need it. You should create a different method that doesn't add the parameters when not needed